# Is .js extension needed for Javascript files in browser?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

Can things like `<script type="text/javascript" src="/actions/generateScript"></script>` be used without troubles?
It's kinda hard and tricky to setup server for processing urls with extensions, so maybe I just don't need them.

Comment: Did you already try it yourself in the browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not needed. Browser just tries to download resource from `src` and execute it as JS code.

I once have use `.php` file as CSS source and it worked fine

Answer (score 1):

No, since you already have "script type="text/javascript" the browser knows you are attempting to load a .js file. In addition modern browsers will run javascript regardless.